# converting to list comprehension

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have this code:

```
result = []
for x in [10, 20, 30]:
    for y in [2, 3, 4]:
        if y > 0:
            result.append(x ** y)
```

result

```
[100, 1000, 10000, 400, 8000, 160000, 900, 27000, 810000]
```

I'm trying to convert it to list comprehension with no luck(new in python)

This is my attempt:

```
print [ x ** y if y > 0 for x in [10, 20, 30] for y in [2, 3, 4]]
```

But there is a problem in the statement, any help will be most appropriated.

error:

```
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print [ x ** y if y > 0 for x in [10, 20, 30] for y in [2, 3, 4]]
                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The filtering condition has to be at the end, like this

```
print [x ** y for x in [10, 20, 30] for y in [2, 3, 4] if y > 0]
```

because the [grammar for list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#list-displays) is defined like this

```
list_display        ::=  "[" [expression_list | list_comprehension] "]"
list_comprehension  ::=  expression list_for
list_for            ::=  "for" target_list "in" old_expression_list [list_iter]
list_iter           ::=  list_for | list_if
list_if             ::=  "if" old_expression [list_iter]
```

So only expressions can come before the `for..in` and `if` statement can come only after that.

In your case, `expression` is satisfied by `x ** y` and then `list_for` is satisfied by `for x in [10, 20, 30]` and then another `list_for` is satisfied by `for x in [10, 20, 30]` and finally the `list_if` is satisfied by `if y > 0`. It is of the form

```
[ expression list_for list_for list_if ]
```

BTW, you can do the same with [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product), like this

```
from itertools import product
print [num**power for num,power in product([10, 20, 30], [2, 3, 4]) if power > 0]
```

Comment: You might show how to incorporate the filter in the `itertools` version (perhaps using `itertools.ifilter` on the second argument to `product`).

Answer (score 6):

You need the if statement at the end of the [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

```
print [ x ** y for x in [10, 20, 30] for y in [2, 3, 4] if y > 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Remember this Syntax for Comprehension. '{}' for dict comprehension

```
[ expression for target1 in iterable1 if condition1
for target2 in iterable2 if condition2 ...
for targetN in iterableN if conditionN ]
```